# How to trace out letters like a laser

Tags: javascript, svg, smil

Looking for ideas on how to animate what looks like a laser drawing out a word in a cursive font using SVG.  The animation can be done with SMIL or JavaScript I don't care - though I think it would be easier with SMIL.

I am pretty sure if I could just get the letters represented as a path I could figure out how to animate a line from a fixed point to the word path - even if the path is non-continuous.

Any ideas?

EDIT
My demo was very basic, essentially I wrote animate functions for each letter and arranged their timing.  Here is the letter X for example:

```
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
   <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="black"/>

   <path id="word" stroke="red" d="M10 10 L40 40 M40 10 L10 40" />
   <line x1="10" y1="10" x2="25" y2="50" stroke="blue" stroke-width="0.5">
      <animate attributeName="x1" begin="0s" dur="1s" values="10; 40;" />
      <animate attributeName="y1" begin="0s" dur="1s" values="10; 40;" />
      <animate attributeName="x1" begin="1s" dur="1s" values="40; 10;" />
      <animate attributeName="y1" begin="1s" dur="1s" values="10; 40;" />
      <set attributeName="visibility" to="hidden" begin="2s" />
   </line>

</svg>
```

I am sure we can all agree that this is not an ideal long term solution...  I thought it would be relatively easy to animate one end of a LINE along a path but I am having problems just getting the path...

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Yes, but my client wants a complex cursive font, what I demo'd was simple block letters - and they loved it.  I simply don't have the time to go through a trial and error process to mimic a cursive font accurately...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract the paths from the glyphs in question, then apply a dash-array animation as seen in [this example](http://xn--dahlstrm-t4a.net/svg/smil/pen-stroke-animation.svg) on each of the paths.

Comment: How would I "extract the paths from the glyphs in question"?

Comment: FTR I plan on using getTotalLength() and getPointAtLength(float) to draw the laser line.  Your suggestion is perfect for gradually drawing the text - thanks very much and +1.

Comment: Easiest is probably to convert the font to an svgfont and then copy the paths from the corresponding glyph elements (the syntax is the same as in the `d` attribute in paths). Do note that you need to scale the glyph paths, and that the y-axis is flipped compared to normal paths, but it's easy enough to use transforms to get it to look as you want.

Comment: I found a free tool that allows me to convert a font to a path - Inkscape.  Now I have all the parts - thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

From a high level perspective, I would think you would want to do something like render the font to a canvas, then use the pixel information to generate the animation sequence.  A simple algorithm could just trace from left to right, it would be a good deal harder to figure out a single stroke path, but that is doable as well.

You don't mention any idea of what platform or any time constraints, so its hard to get much closer than that.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility... SVG Fonts are, I understand, stored as a sequence of SVG commands used to draw individual characters.  The vector-based nature of drawing in SVG would seem like it would be amenable to 'tracing out' characters in realtime; you might be able to make a conversion utility to pre-convert SVG fonts to simple paths.